# Painting individual pixels quickly in P5.js

Tags: graphics, p5.js

I am trying to make an old TV static type effect in P5.js, and although I am able to make the effect work, the frame rate is quite low.

My approach is the following:

- Loop through each pixel
- Set the stroke to a random value
- Call the point() function to paint the pixel

Initially, I was doing this in the draw function directly but it was very slow. I was getting less than 1 frame a second. So I switch to the following paint buffer approach:

```
const SCREEN_WIDTH = 480
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480

var ScreenBuffer;

function setup(){
    createCanvas(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    ScreenBuffer = createGraphics(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
}

function draw(){
paintBuffer();
image(ScreenBuffer,0,0);
}

function paintBuffer(){
    console.log("Painting Buffer")
    for(var x = 0; x< SCREEN_WIDTH; x++){
        for(var y = 0; y< SCREEN_HEIGHT; y++){
            ScreenBuffer.stroke(Math.random() * 255)
            ScreenBuffer.point(x,y)
        }
    }
}
```

Although I am getting a performance improvement, its nowhere near the 30 frames a second I want to be at. Is there a better way to do this?

The only way I can get reasonable performance is by filling up the screen with small squares instead with the following code:

```
for(var x = 0; x< SCREEN_WIDTH-10; x+=10){
        for(var y = 0; y< SCREEN_HEIGHT-10; y+=10){
            //ScreenBuffer.stroke(Math.random() * 255)
            //ScreenBuffer.point(x,y)
            ScreenBuffer.fill(Math.random() * 255);
            ScreenBuffer.noStroke()
            ScreenBuffer.rect(x,y,10,10)
        }
    }
```

But I would really like a pixel effect - ideally to fill the whole screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe it or not, it's actually the call to `stroke()` that's slowing down your sketch. You can get around this by setting the value of the pixels directly, using the `set()` function or accessing the `pixels` array directly.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/), but here's a simple example:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {

    for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            var c = random(255);
            set(i, j, c);
        }
    }
    updatePixels();

    text(frameRate(), 20, 20);
}
```

Another approach you might consider is generating a few buffers that contain static images ahead of time, and then using those to draw your static. There's really no need to make the static completely dynamic, so do the work once and then just load from image files or buffers created using the `createGraphics()` function.